# Git (host) + shared webhost - workflow?

Tags: git, workflow, shared-hosting

I have this really nice webhost that I really like and I would like to stay there.
I have this really nice git curiosity to work with, so GitHub is the place to go.

Unfortunately, the host don't support git, or any other subversion system.

My question is: 
How can I marry both under some development workflow?
The files will be on the webhost and the "git repository" on gitHub can this be done?

Update:
The host doesn't provide shell access so I believe. (Not confirmed).
If they do support, what should I ask?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Comment: Does the host give you shell access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your host doesn't support Git you'll have to get a little creative with your deploy strategy. For development, you should be good since your development machine can push/pull from gihub.

You can deploy to your web server from Github by using the downloads feature. When you're ready to deploy a release, tag your repo and push the tag up to github ( `git push --tags` ). On github, this will create a download tarball. From your webhost, just wget this download into your directory and un-tar it to the directory that serves the webpages. You may need to copy in your configuration files that aren't in the repo.

You can also do all this with the [git bundle command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html).

Comment: thanks a lot.  With your answer a question arrived to me: Since we are developing with git, let's say we are two developers (that we actually are), we don't need to see the website on a shared host while developing right? The only thing we need is to develop locally, see our web application locally, and "with git help" we can be sure that, what is on his local environment is the same as what is on my local environment. Is this true?

Comment: To be honest I found this workflow quite complex already. So when I hear "get creative" I read: "here: some more things to do" ;) - the main point is simplify. If It can't be simple, than I switch to a host company that does support git - I'm starting to planning some development workflow for the very first time. :D

Comment: @MEM - What I meant by "get creative" is that it won't be as simple as a lot of other people are used to working. If your host supports git, you usually just push all production changes to your master branch. Then, on your host, you just run `git pull origin master` and you application is deployed. Your current host just requires you to use the download step. To answer your first question, you are correct. You can view your site on your localhost (and your other developer too) without pushing it up to your web host.

Comment: Thanks again. So, if I find a shared host with git support, I will have no need to git hub. But I wish NOT to work directly on the clients shared host server, instead I would like to a) work locally, b) submit files and repository changes (if this makes sense) to the shared host with git support), once this is done, it will be a question of c) passing them to the client shared host server (that could not have git support). For doing this c) part, should we, when we finish the job, create some sort of "prodution final git thing" or it would be a meter of just uploading the files?

Comment: Another thing that I found really hard to think is: Common we should have a list of tasks to do, like: Fix issue A, Test issue B... where does that enters on the workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If the host gives you shell access :

```
git clone <your repo>
```

If you have shell access and not git, you can compile git in your user directory.

Else, you could set-up a git-hook that pushes to your ftp/....

Here's the guide to git hooks : http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html
You set it up on your own directory so that it issues the command to push to your ftp

Comment: The host doesn't support git, he can't simply clone

Comment: thanks for your information. Unfortunately for me, I don't understand it. Where should I issue that git clone command - taking that the host don't have git. Should I pass it to my local computer and then to the shared host? I don't know how to compile anything so I believe, nor what I need to do that. what is a hook ? Sorry for all those questions.

Answer (score 1):

One potential alternative to hooks is https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp, a script you would run from your local machine that makes dealing with FTP a bit less painful by uploading only changed files. I would continue to use GitHub (or another git hosting solution) for backup/collaboration purposes, but you can then also "deploy" to your shared web host using git-ftp.

On a separate note: While I understand your desire to stick with your shared web host, I highly recommend that you consider upgrading to a VPS or similar at some point. Having git on my VPS (and making it a part of my workflow and deploy strategy) saves **hours** of work. Even shell access alone can dramatically speed things up, once you start learning how to take advantage of it.

Perhaps your shared web host also offers a VPS plan?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access, you can write a custom post-receive hook on github.com.  You deployed code should be symbolically linked from another directory outside your webroot and after every deployment you can change the symbolic link to the last updated code.  Make sure that you don't upload the .git folder or make sure that apache doesn't serve those files.

Comment: at least I realise that post-receive hook could be a solution - I wish I could grasp what it his. I will have to have a look. I realise that I have more basic workflow question do deal with, before this one. :(

Comment: A post-receive hook is a script that will be fired on a git repository as soon as it receives a new update.

Comment: So simple. :) Thanks. I will mark you last comment as "great comment". Normally I get such complicated answers for such a simple question. :)